# Convert String containing Array of Integer to Integer Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sending `JSON` from front end and reading it in JAVA(back end)  where a variable abc contains list of integers.

I have a `String locationjson = "["12","55","62","90"]";`

And I want to convert it to `Arraylist / List<Integer>` in java... i have searched on stackOverflow for answer but it is solve in case of Javascript , I want solution in java.

Comment: parseInt would not do you??

Comment: Why don’t you use a JSON library to parse it then use `parseInt` on each string?

Comment: Is this String object -> `String locationjson = "["12","55","62","90"]";`?

Answer (score 1):

```
String abc = "[\"12\",\"55\",\"62\",\"90\"]";
String[] stringArray = abc.substring(1, abc.length() - 1).split(",");
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s: stringArray)     {
    integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to find your int from this String so you can use this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "\"[\"12\",\"55\",\"62\",\"90\"]\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: superb ...very very  thanks man......its working...

Comment: you are welcome @VaibhavShimpi